# String Manipulation using Node JS

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

I'm newbie in Node JS. How can I manipulate this sentence "Architecture, Royal Melbourne Institute of Technology.", I just want to put words before comma (in this case *Architecture*)? So if I find comma, I'll put all words before the first comma.

Comment: Can't you just remove the comma?

Comment: If you don't know regex probably string.split array.splice and array.join

Comment: can you tell us the expected output? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh
input = "Architecture, Royal Melbourne Institute of Technology". 
output = "Architecture".
The logic: find first comma and put words before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use split function.

```
var str = "Architecture, Royal Melbourne Institute of Technology";
console.log(str.split(",")[0]);// logs Architecture
```

output array after splitting your string by `,` would have the expected result at the zeroth index.

Answer (score 0):

Its again a normal Javascript, all the methods can be used in nodeJS.
var name = "any string";
For example:

```
var str = "Hi, world",
arrayOfStrings = str.split(','),
output = arrayOfStrings[0]; // output contains "Hi"
```

You can update the required field by directly replacing the string ie.

```
arrayOfStrings[0] = "other string";
str = arrayOfStrings.join(' '); // "other string world"
```

Point to be noted: 
If we update the output, as we are updating the string it contains the copy NOT the reference, while joining it gives the same text ie, "Hi world".
So we need to change the reference value ie arrayOfStrings[0] then .join(' ') will combine the required string.